# Open Word document from Excel (Office 2016 and MacOS)

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I am trying to open a Word document through VBA from Excel. I get

> Run-time error 2146959355 (80080005)

I need to copy data from Excel to Word, but system can't open the Word document.

Part of my code:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet, msWord As Object

Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set msWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

With msWord
    .Visible = True
    .Documents.Open ThisWorkbook.Path & "~/Desktop/! Rezervační smlouva - vzor.docx"
    .Activate
```

Comment: I have not tested my code in Office 2016 but I doubt it should matter. Can you test the code that I posted? Do not change anything in it. Paste the entire code in a module and run that code. You will be asked to select a word file. Select the relevant file and click open. Does it work for you?

Answer (score 4):

You may be getting that error because

1. MAC doesn't support `/` as path separator. It uses `:` as a path separator.

[image]

2. Your MS Office does not have the latest updates.

**Tried and Tested in EXCEL 2011**

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim oWord As Object

    Set oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

    oWord.Visible = True

    Ret = Application.GetOpenFilename()

    oWord.documents.Open (Ret)
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? Can you be a little more elaborate? Also did you copy and use the code as it is?

Answer (score 0):

Code:

Dim oWord As Object

```
Set oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

oWord.Visible = True

Ret = Application.GetOpenFilename()

oWord.documents.Open (Ret)
```

Comment: And Mac writes: Run-Time error '-2146959355 (80080005)'